# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AnchorPane[id=klantroot, styleClass=root]is already set as root of another scene

Tags: javafx, modal-dialog, window

I am trying to build a simple appliaction using JavaFX. The problem is when i open a window (modal) the first time it is going well. The second time it's giving me this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AnchorPane[id=klantroot,
>   styleClass=root]is already set as root of another scene

Since i am quite new to this I really don't have an idea on how to fix this. Can someone provide some help please. Thanks a lot in advance.

In my maincontroller I have this code:

```
private void showModal(Parent view, String title) {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Scene scene = new Scene(view);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    stage.initOwner(this.root.getScene().getWindow());
    stage.setTitle(title);
    stage.showAndWait();
}

@FXML
private void handleToevoegenKlant() {
    klantPresenter.setKlant(-1);        
    showModal(klantPresenter.getView(), "Toevoegen klant");
}
```

In my klantPresenter i have:

```
@FXML private Parent klantroot;

.....

public Parent getView() {
    return klantroot;
}

@FXML
private void close() {
    Stage stage = (Stage)getView().getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close(); 
}
```

The code for KlantView.fxml starts with:

```
<AnchorPane 
    fx:id="klantroot"
    fx:controller="presenter.KlantPresenter"
    prefHeight="274.0" prefWidth="483.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
```

Answer (score 3):

Every `Scene` can have only one root element and every `Parent` node can only be set as root for a just one scene. To set the parent as root to another scene you need to break previous relation.

The code `Scene scene = new Scene(view);` in `showModal(...)` method will assign the view as a root to the scene. So when the `showModal(...)` is called again with the **same instance** of parent view, the error will arise.

The solution can vary depending on your app logic:

1) Create new instance of Parent view and send it as an argument.

2) Add lines into `showModal(...)`

```
if(view.getScene() != null)
    view.getScene().setRoot(null);
```

to break old relation.

3) Your own solution?

Comment: I was having similar issue but i am getting scene'e root cannot be null when i try to set the root.